# printing something that includes text and variables

Tags: python

Super Easy question, but I'm have a brain fart.
I have the following variables: hours, minutes, seconds
I'm trying to write the following statement:

```
"I have worked (hours) hours, (minutes) minutes, and (seconds) seconds"
```

The parentheses indicate the variable.

How would i write that?

```
msg = "I have worked (hours) hours, (minutes) minutes, and (seconds) seconds"
```

Comment: You could just search on Internet or "How to print in Python". Are just read Python docs.

Comment: Homework, homework, homework, homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
print "I have worked %s hours, %s minutes, and %s seconds" % (hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: agh duh! stupid me. thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format), using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is more preferred:

```
>>> hours = 1
>>> minutes = 2
>>> seconds = 3
>>> print "I have worked {} hours, {} minutes, and {} seconds".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
I have worked 1 hours, 2 minutes, and 3 seconds
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own parser, you professor will find it extremely impressive:

```
# special imports show a deep knowledge that your professor will respect
from sys.stdout import write as print

s = "I have worked (hours) hours, (minutes) minutes, and (seconds) seconds"

vs = [hours, minutes, seconds]
rv = ''

in_variable = False
v_count = 0

# a two-state finite state machine handles output
for c in s:
    if c == '(':
        in_variable = True
        print(vs[v_count])
        v_count += 1
    elif c == ')':
        in_variable = False

    if not in_variable:
        print(c)
```